# How to take user to gps coordinates from a listview click

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, gps, fragment

I have recently found myself struggling in taking a user to GPS coordinates directly from my listview. I have not found any examples of this online? First click on the list takes me to a website, i was hoping that the second intent could take the user to google maps and the gps coordinates. As an example, below is the way i have it set up so far. (Also using fragment)

```
             @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                switch(groupPosition) {
                 case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0: 

                        Intent myWebLink= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http:/www.blahblah.com"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink);
                        break;
                    //case 1: 
                        Intent *Link to GPS coordinates*
                        break;//
                    case 2: 
                        Intent d3= new Intent(v.getContext(),class3.class);
                        startActivity(d3);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        Intent d4= new Intent(v.getContext(),class4.class);
                        startActivity(d4);
                        break;
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: you worked with google maps before???

Comment: I presumed that once a location was assigned from the button click, google maps would take over and deal with current location etc? I havent worked with google maps before though so I am only guessing :S

Comment: Fyi,its an external location that i want the button to assign.